# React state not updated in class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

As a backend developer, I am trying to create frontend with React. So, I may have a bit meaningless or simple problem. But I cannot have state updated in the class. However, when I fetch data from backend via axios, inside "render{}" method it gets called.

```
import "./App.css";
import { Component } from "react";
import { getAllStudents } from "./client";
import Container from "./container";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    students: [],
    isFetching: false
  };

  fetchStudents = () => {
    this.setState({isFetching  : true});
    getAllStudents()
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((students) => {
        console.log(students)
        this.setState({students : students, isFetching: false})
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { students, isFetching } = this.state;

     ...
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my client:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'})

export const getAllStudents = () => instance.get('/students', {
    timeout: 5000
})
```

I tried to show data in a table, but it gives an empty array

Comment: Do you call `fetchStudents` anywhere?

Comment: I don't think so. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

React is made up of components. In your case, you used a class component. Now, if you want to interact with an API, you need to use the [componentDidMoint()](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) method.

inside this function you can then retrieve your data and set the state accordingly.

```js
import "./App.css";
import { Component } from "react";
import { getAllStudents } from "./client";
import Container from "./container";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    students: [],
    isFetching: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStudents();
  }

  fetchStudents = () => {
    this.setState({isFetching  : true});
    getAllStudents()
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((students) => {
        console.log(students)
        this.setState({students : students, isFetching: false})
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { students, isFetching } = this.state;

    // Render table here 
  }
}

export default App;
```